# Left justify a text

Tags: tables, xetex, alignment, indic

I want to left justify the numbers when in right aligned text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
some random text. \null\hfill 1 \\
some random text. \null\hfill 2 \\
some random text. \null\hfill 3 \\
some random text. \null\hfill 4 \\
some random text. \null\hfill 5 [1] \\
some random text. \null\hfill 6 \\
some random text. \null\hfill 7 \\
some random text. \null\hfill 8 \\
some random text. \null\hfill 9 \\
some random text. \null\hfill 10 [2] \\

\end{document}
```

The alignment of 4 and 5 and 9 and 10 are not proper. I want the numbers to be left aligned.

For better understanding I will attach a photo of the book.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: (i) not all numbers have equal width, (ii) 5 [1]  and 10 are more than as one digits width wide, (ii) enclose number with some box of constant width, for example `\parbox{2em}{<number>}`

Comment: The usual approach is to put the numbers into a box with a fixed width (see `\pnumwidth` for example).  It has to be wide enough for the largest number you expect to use.  `\makebox` can be used the align to the left, right, or center.

Comment: -Zarko If I use \parbox{2em} the spacing varies as i change the font or fontsize.

Comment: There is no moral justification for text. Text is ethically wrong no matter what.

Comment: @Gaussler - You had me, and then you lost me...

Answer (score 5):

Something like this? (The vertical line indicates the right-hand edge of the text block.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\hfill
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
1 \\
2 \\
3 \\
4 \\
5 [1] \\
6 \\
7 \\
8 \\
9 \\
\llap{1}0 [2]
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Its working for small text but I have a lengthy book to be set like this.

Comment: @karthikholla - Sadly (but likely not surprisingly), my mind-reading skills are absolutely worthless. The best (and only) thing I could do was to base my answer on the information you provided. If your document requires a fundamentally different solution approach, it would be really helpful if you provided more information about what some of these approach requirements might be.

Comment: I have attached a photo for the layout of the book